# MTT assay normalization

Tags: cell-biology, toxicology

Since the precise amount of cells in each well of an MTT assay varies, how can I normalize the results by cell number/concentration?

How can I take into account the number of cells that have already disappeared due to the action of a toxin applied previously as part of this assay?